# In Google Analytic reports my domain name gets added to the page path

Tags: google-analytics

So in my reports instead of '/some/page/' it is '/some/page/domain.name', which is not what I want...

I have checked with Google Chrome dev tools, the page view details are sent correctly to GA (without the domain name). How do I change that behaviour?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the filters added to the view, maybe you have an url rewite filter set in a wrong way.

Comment: Are you using GTM? In this case share your configuration Analytics tag, pls

Comment: I've deleted the view and created a new one, that fixed the problem...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, very curious